# SELECT where date is within X months away regardless of stored year

Tags: mysql, sql, date, comparison

I currently have a query that is getting the records where their `deadline` is less than 3 months away. The `deadline` is stored as a Date, but the year is not important as this record should flag up every year.

My query:

```
SELECT client_name 
FROM client 
WHERE MOD(DAYOFYEAR(deadline) - DAYOFYEAR(CURDATE()), +365) <= 90 
AND DAYOFYEAR(deadline) > DAYOFYEAR(CURDATE())
```

Apologies if there’s errors in the syntax as I’m writing this from memory – but it does work.

It works up until a `deadline` is in the first quarter and the current date is in the final quarter then it no longer returns the record. How do I get around this?

So the query needs to return the records that have a deadline within 3 months of the current date. The Year in the `deadline` date should be ignored as this could be years ago, but it is the day and month of the `deadline` that is important.

Or is the problem the date I am storing? Should I update this each year?

Thanks

Comment: `select ... where now() - interval 3 month < deadline`?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. This does not work when the deadline has a previous year?

Comment: it doesn't care about the year at all. it just looks if the deadline field is less than 3 months old, e.g. deadline = 2015-03-15, now=2015-05-20, now-3 months = 2015-02-20, so `2015-02-20 < 2015-03-15` is TRUE.

Comment: Ah yes sorry it didn't work quite right first time because the condition is the wrong way round. This works perfectly..
SELECT `client_name` FROM `client` WHERE `deadline` <= now() + interval 3 month AND DAYOFYEAR(`deadline`) > DAYOFYEAR(now())
Thanks for your help

Comment: Maxxi: I don't think that condition shown in the comment meets the specification. I think you need a condition more like the one shown in my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach is to use a conditional test like this:

```
WHERE CONCAT(YEAR(NOW()),DATE_FORMAT(d.deadline,'-%m-%d')) 
        + INTERVAL CONCAT(YEAR(NOW()),DATE_FORMAT(d.deadline,'-%m-%d'))<NOW() YEAR
    < NOW() + INTERVAL 3 MONTH
```

We can unpack that a little bit. On that first line, we're creating a "next due" deadline date, by taking the current year, and appending the month and day value from the `deadline`.

But there's a problem. Some of those "next due" deadline dates are in the past. So, to handle that problem (when the 3 month period "wraps" into the next year), we need to add a year to any "next due" deadline date that's *before* the current date.

Now, we can compare that to a date 3 months from now, to determine if the "next due" deadline date is in the next 3 months.

That's a bit complicated.

Here's a SQL Fiddle as a demonstration: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c90e9/3.

For testing, `NOW()` is inconvenient because it always returns today's date. So, for testing, we replace all occurrences of `NOW()` with a user-defined variable **`@now`**, and set that to various dates, so we can appropriately test.

Here's the SQL statement I used for testing. The first expression is the conditional test we're planning on using in the `WHERE` clause. For testing, we want to return all the rows, and just see which rows get `due_in_3mo` flagged as `TRUE` (`1`) and which get flagged as `FALSE` (`0`).

The second expression in the SELECT list just the "next due" deadline date, same as used in the first expression.

The rest of the expressions are pretty self-explanatory... we also want to display the date 3 months in the future we're comparing to, and the original "deadline" date value.

```
SELECT 
       CONCAT(YEAR(@now),DATE_FORMAT(d.deadline,'-%m-%d')) 
       + INTERVAL CONCAT(YEAR(@now),DATE_FORMAT(d.deadline,'-%m-%d'))<@now YEAR 
       < @now + INTERVAL 3 MONTH   
    AS `due_in_3mo`

     , CONCAT(YEAR(@now),DATE_FORMAT(d.deadline,'-%m-%d')) 
       + INTERVAL CONCAT(YEAR(@now),DATE_FORMAT(d.deadline,'-%m-%d'))<@now YEAR 
    AS `next_due`

     , d.id
     , d.deadline + INTERVAL 0 DAY AS `deadline`
     , @now + INTERVAL 3 MONTH AS `now+3mo`
     , @now + INTERVAL 0 DAY AS `now`
  FROM d d
 CROSS
  JOIN (SELECT @now := '2015-11-01') i
 ORDER BY d.id
```

Change the value assigned to `@now` in the inline view (aliased as `i`) to test with other date values.

(You may want to use `DATE(NOW())` in place of `NOW()` so that times don't get mixed in, and you may want to subtract another day from that, that really just depends how you want to handle the edge case of a `deadline` with month and day the *same* as the current date. (i.e. do you want to handle that as "in the past" or not.)

To summarize the approach: generate the "next due" deadline date as a DATE value in the future, and compare to the a date 3 months from now.

Comment: well mybe overingeneering you could do this with WEEKOFYEAR and then calculate from there (depanding on how precise you need it)

Comment: @Jester: You're right, it might be over engineered. The solution only needs to be as precise as it needs to be. If `WEEKOFYEAR` is a better approach, then have at it. Personally, I don't like solutions that "sort of" work "most of the time". I prefer solutions that can be demonstrated to work *every* time, and meet the specification 100%. In cases where it's not feasible to satisfy the specification, then we negotiate to change the requirement, so we do have a requirement that can be satisfied, 100% correct, accurate and precise.

Comment: That is perfect! Thank you very much for giving me the correct solution  but also explaining it and giving me the statement used for testing, this is extremely helpful!

Comment: Maxxi:  feel free to use `CURDATE()` in place of `NOW()`.  I should have used `CURDATE` (or `DATE(NOW())`) in my example `WHERE` clause, at a minimum, the last occurrence on the second line and the third line,  `<NOW()`.  That includes time portion, and we probably want to truncate off that time portion, so we don't exclude items that are "due today". Also, I only ran a few test cases. The "trick" is really getting the "next due" from the deadline date. I wish there was a more elegant expression to implement what seems to be a pretty simple idea.

Comment: Maxxi: the expressions I gave really do need to be tested, especially the boundary cases... deadline is today, deadline is yesterday, deadline is tomorrow, in combination with `@now` in December, Dec 31, Jan 1, etc., tests to cover those troublesome edge and corner cases. If you discover a problems with corner case, let me know, and I'll take a closer look. (I'm convinced that the approach is pretty solid.)

Comment: I've had a play around with the SQL Fiddle and also locally and It does seem solid. Though I will test this thoroughly at work tomorrow and let you know if I come across any issues. Thanks again!

Comment: Regarding your other comment, is there any advantage to using CURDATE over NOW?

Comment: No real advantage, just a difference. `CURDATE()` returns only the date,  with time assumed to be midnight. `NOW()` returns date and time. I am just used to lopping off the time (when I need to) with `DATE(NOW())`. My preference for `NOW()` is mostly informed by the behavior of Oracle `SYSDATE`, just a very familiar pattern for me. Also, the documentation for `NOW()` includes important point about *when* the function is evaluated, which is not documented for `CURDATE()`. Reference: [**NOW()**](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_now)